# Ordinals and power set of ordinals. Solution explanation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I read that for an ordinal $\alpha\geq 2$, $\mathcal{P}(\alpha)$ is not an ordinal but I am a but confused by my teacher's explanation.

I should also say our course defined an ordinal to be a transitive set and well ordered by $\in.$

Q1: So first question I got was that $\mathcal{P}(2)$ is not an ordinal and the explanation goes something like this:

'$\{ 0\}, \{1\}\in\mathcal{P}(2)$ but they are not well-ordered by $\in$'.

My confusion is that why is not well-odered by $\in$? I thought $\{0\}\in\{1\}$ because we take $\{0\}=1$? Hence I thought this way the subset containing $\{0\},\{1\}$ does have a minimum element?

Q2: So after this explanation, my teacher said for $\alpha\geq 2$, $\{1,2\}\in\mathcal{P}(\alpha)$ and so $\mathcal{P}(\alpha)$ is not an ordinal. Why is this true? Also, I thought it is not true that $\{1,2\}\in\mathcal{P}(2)?$

Thank you so so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume "well-ordered" was supposed to be "comparable". With that in mind, in this context it should be true, and in my opinion it isn't a technicality, that $\{0\}\in \{1\}$ because $1=\{0\}$. Therefore $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are comparable. However, $\emptyset$ and $\{1\}$ aren't, which incidentally implies that $\mathcal P(\alpha)$ isn't an ordinal for any $\alpha>1$. Notice that $\mathcal P(0)=\{\emptyset\}$ and $\mathcal P(1)=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ are ordinals.

*Added:* If it was meant to actually be "well-ordered", then these sets are obviously well-ordered by the relation $\in$, because any one-element set is strictly well-ordered by the empty relation.

Comment: Thank you so much! May I please ask why does comparable mean? I went back to check the notes my teacher did say $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are not comparable without defining what comparable means.

Comment: If you use this definition of [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set), then two elements $a$, $b$ in a partially ordered set $(X,\le)$ are comparable if and only if $a\le b$ or $b\le a$. If on the other hand you call "partial order" what I would call a [strict partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders), then two elements $a$, $b$ in a strict partial order $(X,<)$ should be elements such that $a<b$ or $b<a$ or $a=b$ (I think).